# DrawerArrowStyle with windowActionBarOverlay color in Toolbar

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I'm implementing Material Design into my app and I'm stuck on style of my `DrawerToggle` with `windowActionBarOverlay`.

I'm setting the `DrawerArrowStyle` in my `styles.xml` and when running on device I have a different color in whole `ToolBar`:

Transparent `ToolBar`:
[image]

With title and action:
[image]

This is only happening on pre-Lollipop devices. I suspect that it's some compatibility on my styles, but until now I couldn't figure out what it's.

In my other style (without `windowActionBarOverlay`) it works perfectly in any device.

Here's my styles:

```
<style name="StyleOverlay" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_blue</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/translucentDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeWithoutOverlay" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_blue</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/translucentDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="drawableSize">40dp</item>
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeToolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_blue</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/orange</item>
</style>
```

My layout toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeToolbar" />
```

In my Activity:

```
...
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
...
```

Does anyone know whats happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the Google Android Docs, from the [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html)

> To avoid resizing your layout when the action bar hides and shows, you can enable overlay mode for the action bar. When in overlay mode, your activity layout uses all the space available as if the action bar is not there and the system draws the action bar in front of your layout. This obscures some of the layout at the top, but now when the action bar hides or appears, the system does not need to resize your layout and the transition is seamless.

Setting the windowactionbaroverlay to true will create a 60% transparent black gradient over the action bar. Hence you can see a color of BLUE + (60% TRANSPARENT BLACK) = BLUISH GREEN. Sorry about my color definitions.

You need to set an extra property here on your activity's parent layout i.e.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize">
...</RelativeLayout>
```

as mentioned in the docs. Please refer them.

Comment: That's not the issue, i'm already doing that on my fragments... My problem it's only the color of components on my toolbar